# 7 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, any 4 of them linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If possible, how can I take 7 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that any 4 of them are linearly independent? Any solution will be welcomed, even if non constructive.

Comment: It is possible.  Start with a choice of any four basis vectors.  Each time you choose a new vector, you need to avoid a choice $v$ which gives a span of less than four dimensions in combination with any three of the previous vectors.  So the finite number of three dimensional subspaces of "bad" choices will never cover $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: That's the first thing I considered, but was unable to success, mostly due to the fact that I tried weird component-by-component combinations which finally failed. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Take any seven vectors at random - will work with probability $1$.

Why only $7$? Here are uncountably many: $(1,a,a^2,a^3)$ as $a$
varies through $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your point, it worked. Is there any way to take truly random numbers on a continuous space? Shall I throw a dice like infinite times?

Comment: You could generate each coordinate according to a Gaussian distribution (or a uniform distribution, or whatever). On a computer, a random number generator does not generate a true uniform(0,1) distribution but some discrete values within the set. However, since the number of discrete values the random number generator can take is so high, you'd probably spend a very long time in order to get a collection of 7 vectors which don't work.